# Weird Spaces Appear Even When Scrollbar is Disabled

Tags: html, css

[image]

So I have this website which for some reason displays these blank spaces where the scrollbar is supposed to appear. The entire body is set to 100% width and height so I don't think it's an issue with the size of the body. I think it's just an invisible scrollbar or something but I'm not sure how I would remove it. The weirdest thing is that this issue only appears when the screen is set to some smaller ratios...

```css
body {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
  font-family: var(--font);
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  user-select: none;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Note: My website isn't google docs, it's just a copy of it.

Comment: try `html { padding: 0; margin: 0; }`

Comment: @EricFortis tried it, no change

Comment: There is not enough information in  your question for us to do anything but guess at an answer. Please put enough code in so that we can run it and see the problem for ourselves. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example and have you used your browser's devtools to see exactly what CSS is being applied where?

Comment: I think it's just a glitch with the preview in the sizing because it looks fine when I'm actually on a screen of that size.

Answer (score 0):

You can try in your css:

```
* {
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Comment: Same thing happens, side note, what does *, ::before, ::after do?

Comment: @Walker. The asterisk or star selects all the elements in your page. The ::before it's a pseudo-selector used to add cosmetic content into a element https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::before
In fact you don't need the before and after. What this piece of code do is take all elements and remove the padding and border.